# Issue with redirect_to in controller action & load modal html (bootstrap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, view, controller

I'm having a slight issue with a controller action. The behavior i'm after is the option to edit a note.   I want the user to be able to edit the note, just like they created the note, in a modal(twitter bootstrap).   Creating a note this way works fine.    The problem is coming to edit the note.   The main issue is that I need to always know the exact note id when a user clicks on a "edit" button.   To complicate things a bit more,  there is a "dashboard" controller/model which acts as a container for "notes" and other things.

Here is the code/link I have in the view on the dashboard which displays all the users current notes.

```
        = link_to "Edit Note", "update_note/#{n.id}",{:note_id => "#{n.id}"}
```

So Here I am sending some params contain the note id.   Then in the controller action, in the dashboard (the container)

```
          def update_note
            @user         = current_user
            @edit_note_id = params[:params1]
            redirect_to dashboard_path and return
            respond_to do |format|
               format.html { render "#modal_edit_notes"}
            end
          end
```

So at point I have the unique note id, and instantiating something so when hopefully the modal loads up I can create a form based on that.   The issue that I'm having is getting the controller at this point to go back to the dashboard, and pop up the modal, now that I have the note.id.

To trigger the modal,  I normally would do a

```
          href = #modal_edit_notes, data-toggle = "modal"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have two options here.

1. Embed a form inside a hidden element for every single note you display, and then just have that pre-rendered form show up in the modal when you want to edit that particular note.
2. Load the content of the modal via ajax, this will require a little bit of custom JS to make it work with the bootstrap modals, but isn't too difficult. This is how I would do it.

Also, as a side point, the `update_note` method really should be a `update` method in a `NotesController`.